# Ember. Custom createRecord for DS.Adapter doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, adapter, ember-cli

I'am creating a form inside my Addon that will save the record in the store and also will send a JSON object through a post api call to a rails backend.

My issue is that the method "createRecord" doesn't get overwritten by a custom one inside my adapter. It basically creates the record, but by using the default "createRecord" ember-data method.

addon/adapters/trade.js

```
 import Ember from 'ember';
 import ApplicationAdapter from '../adapters/application';


 export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  createRecord: function(store, type, snapshot, trade) {
    debugger;
    console.log('bla')
   }
 });
```

app/adapters/trade.js

```
export { default } from 'ember-p/adapters/trade';
```

addon/models/trade.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
 offer: DS.belongsTo('offer', {async: true}),

 firstName: DS.attr('string'),
 lastName: DS.attr('string'),
 streetName1: DS.attr('string'),
 streetName2: DS.attr('string'),
 city: DS.attr('string'),
 state: DS.attr('string'),
 zipcode: DS.attr('string'),
 telephone: DS.attr('string'),
 email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

addon/routes/checkout.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

 actions: {

  createTrade: function (trade) {
    this.store.createRecord('trade',trade);
    this.transitionTo('thanks');
   },
  }
});
```

app/templates/checkout.hbs

{{
    p-address
    createTrade="createTrade"
   }}

app/templates/components/p-address.hbs

```
{{yield}}

<h1>Address form</h1>
 <form {{action 'createTrade' value="target.value" on="submit"}}>
 <div class="form-group">
   {{input type="text" placeholder="First name" value=firstName}}
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="form-group">
  {{input type="text" placeholder="Last name" value=lastName}}
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="form-group">
   {{input type="text" placeholder="Street name 1" value=streetName1}}
 </div>
 <br>
  <div class="form-group">
   {{input type="text" placeholder="Street name 2" value=streetName2}}
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{input type="text" placeholder="City" value=city}}
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
   {{input type="text" placeholder="State" value=state}}
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
   {{input type="text" placeholder="Zipcode"value=zipcode}}
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    {{input type="text" placeholder="Telephone" value=telephone}}
   </div>
   <br>
  <div class="form-group">
   {{input type="submit" value="submit"}}
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call `createRecord` on the adapter but on the store itself. You can override the `service:store` as well, if you really want that, but why would you do that?

```
export default DS.Store.extend({
  createRecord() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    debugger;
  }
});
```

The adapter is an adapter between the store and the backend. So it won't know when the record is created but only when it gets saved. To save the record call `.save()` on it:

```
this.store.createRecord('trade',trade).save(); // will return a promise
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lux.  How do you think I should proceed to do it?
My idea is that I need an adapter and a serializer to make the post api call with an object that is accepted for the api.
Maybe createRecord is not what I'm looking for. What do you think?

Comment: Why not call `.save()`?

Comment: Awesome! I get to the method in the adapter now. Thanks!